# Possible to use to_string in a loop with getline?

Tags: c++, string, loops, tostring

I have a text file with the sample text

```
a b c d 
e f g h 
i j k l
```

and I want to loop through each line and store it as a string. As of right now I am trying to use the following for loop:

```
ifstream inputFile;
inputFile.open("input.txt");

int totalLines = 3;
for(int i; i < totalLines; i++){
    getline(inputFile, to_string(i));
}
```

where totalLines is equal to the # of lines (in this case 3) and I want to assign each line to the respective "i" value but I am getting this error:

> error: no matching function for call to ‘getline(std::ifstream&, std::string)’ getline(inputFile, to_string(i));

Is there a way to fix this, or perhaps even a better route to loop through multiple lines and assign them to a respective string for use later?

Answer (score 0):

That makes no sense. The `std::getline` function reads a line into a an *lvalue* string. The string returned by `std::to_string` isn't an lvalue, and it won't magically store all three strings in different locations.

Just *guessing* here, but I think you want to use an vector (or an array) of strings, and set each element of the vector to the line you read.

Perhaps something like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> all_lines;
std::string one_line;
while (std::getline(inputFile, one_line))
{
    all_lines.emplace_back(one_line);
}
```

Note that I use a `while` loop instead, and that it's guaranteed to read all lines no matter how many there are in the file (unless there's an error, in which case it will stop reading).

You can print the lines like this:

```
for (auto const& l : all_lines)
{
    std::cout << l << '\n';
}
```

Or if you want the line numbers:

```
for (unsigned i = 0; i < all_lines.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << "Line #" << i + 1 << ": " << all_lines[i] << '\n';
}
```